# error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, electron, electron-packager

I ran electron packager for Linux and windows environment. The build is working as expected in Windows but not in Linux .It complains about

" error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I run this in SuSE Linux flavour, I am not sure what I am missing.

This is electron-packager for Linux

```
"builderForLinux": "electron-packager --out Linux64 --overwrite --platform linux --appname clientsettings . --icon=./xyz.png --executable-name ClientSettings --asar.unpackDir=node_modules/regedit"
```

[Link to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941314/electron-package-doesnt-start-in-linux-environmenterror-while-loading-shared-l)

Answer (score -2):

hello!
It seems that you have a missing package that provides a library required for your project to work; the thing here would be if your repository provides it, you can do that by running:
yum whatprovides libgtk-3.so.0

If for some bad luck your official repositories do not have that library available (sometimes it happens) then, if you are using Suse Pro, perhaps opensuse's RPM may work, but, that would be a coin in the air; be careful and backup any data that may be critical just in case you want to proceed.

After installed you may try again and see if everything works out.
Hopefully this will solve your issue!

Peace out!